# Does python has a Key Derivation Function (kdf) module used in Wifi Protected Setup (WPS)?

Tags: python

I have tried browsing python's documentation website to determine if there is a Key Derivation Function (kdf) module. The kdf is a function used in the Wifi Protected Setup (WPS) to generate keys for the WPS process.However, I haven't found anything..Is there such a module in python? I am certain there is though because I have seen python codes with such a function.thanks for your help!

the piece of code below, I have extracted from a program that uses kdf

```
elf.AuthKey, self.KeyWrapKey, self.EMSK = self.kdf(KDK, 'Wi-Fi Easy and Secure Key Derivation', [256, 128, 256])
```

Comment: Do you know which KDF is used in the WPS protocol? (KDF is a type of technique, not the name of a particular algorithm.)

Comment: OP is likely referring to this code https://gist.github.com/duksis/3739250; kdf() is defined within, it does not come from a Python module